# Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch' in spyder, works fine in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, spyder

I'm trying to learn python for a class. we're using jupyter notebooks where the import torch command works fine but using spyder I keep getting this error and I have no idea how to fix it. I'm a complete newbie at this and I really don't know what to do.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read our [guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this

```
 conda install torch     # Use anaconda prompt
```

or

```
 pip install torch   # Use the command prompt
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Spyder terminal and try running `conda install torch` if using Anaconda, or `pip install torch` otherwise.